# IDL code for minimum distance calculation

Tags: performance, iteration, interactive-data-language

I made a program in [IDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDL_(programming_language)) for performing a minimum distance classification on multispectral satellite data. This is what my main function looks like:

```
function minimum_distance, stack, exercising_data

  ;variables
  nbands = get_number_of_bands()
  nclasses = get_number_of_classes()
  x_size = (size(stack, /DIMENSIONS))[0]
  y_size = (size(stack, /DIMENSIONS))[1]
  result = MAKE_ARRAY(x_size,y_size,/INTEGER)

  ;calculate class mean for each class
  class_means = calculate_class_means(exercising_data)

  ;find closest class mean for each point and create result image
  i = 0
  foreach point, stack[0,*,0], i do begin
    foreach point, stack[*,i,0], j do begin
      print, string(i) + "-" + string(j)
      point = REFORM(stack[j,i,*],7,1)
      dist_array = [[point],[class_means]]
      class = (DISTANCE_MEASURE(dist_array))[0:nclasses-1]
      class = min(class,location)
      result[j,i] = location
    end
  end

  ;prepare result for display
  result = result * (255/(nclasses-1))
  result = REVERSE(ROTATE(result,2))

  return, result

end
```

The stack is an array of tif files of Landsat 7 data that I load with the `read_tiff` function. The exercising data looks like this:

```
;Forst
[ $
  [39,25,21,29,14,80,12], $
  [40,25,20,28,11,79,12], $
  [37,24,20,29,14,81,11], $
  [43,28,25,34,14,79,12], $
  [44,29,29,40,13,79,13], $
  [41,27,23,32,14,80,13], $
  [0,0,0,0,0,0,0], $
  [46,31,27,36,13,79,12] $
], $

... (more classes)

;Water
[ $
  [39,24,19,13,9,92,10], $
  [37,22,19,13,9,92,10], $
  [38,24,20,13,9,90,10], $
  [40,24,22,15,9,89,10], $
  [37,22,19,13,10,92,9], $
  [38,23,20,13,10,89,9], $
  [37,23,18,13,9,90,9], $
  [39,25,20,13,9,90,9] $
] $
```

The program actually works, but doesn't have a good performance. This is due to the nested `foreach`-loops within the minimum_distance function. With larger satellite images it takes a very long time to process. I can imagine that you can reach a much better performance using some IDL function that I don't know of. Do you know a way in how I can give this program a better performance and replace the `foreach`-loops?

If you want to take a look at the complete program, [here](https://textuploader.com/1awtu) it is.